# Anchor tag not working inside php code

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have made a live notification system with Php and AJAX. In my notification, it contains a link to redirect for the admin to review.

-->

```
<a class="img-responsive" rel="home" href="index.php"> 
      <img src="img/cbsua.png" style="height: 50px; padding: 2px ;">
</a>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">CBSUA Livestream</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="library.php"><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i> Library</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="question.php"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ask A Question</a>
     </li>
      <li class="dropdown ">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger count" style="border-radius:10px;"></span>
          Notification
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 2px;"></ul>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['User']; ?></a> </li>

</ul>
```

This is what I do to fetch all the data from my database: https://pastebin.com/5Wam23uB

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $id = $row['questId'];

                $output .= '
                    <li>
                        <strong><a href="question.php?id='.$id.'">'.$row["sender"].'</a></strong><br>
                        <small><em>'.$row["question"].'</em></small>
                    </li>
                ';
            }
        }
```

This is not working. The anchor tag inside the output variable. Nothing happens when I click on the supposed to be link in my notification system.

[This is a sample image of my notification. The bold one is where I should click and redirect me to a new url. But nothing happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuOez.png)

Comment: so what exactly doesn't work as you had expected? could you please specify your problem? which anchor doesn't work and what does happen instead?

Comment: I've edited my question :)

Comment: so if u click on that anchor stored in the output var - what does happen? do u get redirected or does nothing change? would be nice if u could provide the url thats in your browser after clicking on the link :)

Comment: Nothing happens. It just stays on the page where my notifications are loaded. When i click on the link, I want it to go: localhost/livetest/question.php=?id and the id of the notification.

Comment: have you tried to inspect the source code of your file - try that by right clicking into your browser window and clicking onto a menu option Called like "show source code" then search for your anchor and copy the uri between the href=""

Comment: Should ‘=id’ be ‘id=‘ when you are building the URL? Looks like you have it backwards.

Comment: Yes, and the result is still the same. Sorry about that. I've edited that in my code just now and tried again but still nothing happens.